Websocket connection fails when adding Spring Boot Security
In a project, I have to implement a live chat between users. To do so I decided to use Websockets.
I currently have a frontend client written in React and a Spring boot backend written in Java.
The client is able to connect to the server's Websocket but as soon as I add the spring-boot-starter-security dependency it breaks giving the following error (in the browser console, no errors nor info in the server console): WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/peer-tutoring-chat-websocket' failed.

Note: I need the security dependency because I need to validate JWT tokens and manage the user's role on the backend, so removing it is not an option.

One of the interesting things is that the code breaks as soon as the dependency is added in the pom.xml file (without changing or adding any new code related to the backend's security). This leads me to think that the problem is related to conflicts within the used libraries.
What I tried:

I inspected the transitive dependencies of the spring-boot-starter-security, hoping to find one in conflict with another but without any success.
I tried to use older versions of the spring-boot-starter-security dependency without any success.

Edit: Often times I also need to remove the com.auth0 java-jwt library in order to make the socket work again, but as with spring-boot-starter-security I cannot remove it permanently since I need it.
Can anyone spot the problem or has dealt with a similar situation in the past? Thank you.
pom.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.somepackage</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>backend</name>
    <description>somedescription</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-azure.version>5.9.1</spring-cloud-azure.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>jwks-rsa</artifactId>
            <version>0.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>3.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

WebSocketConfig file:
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addEndpoint("/mysocket-websocket")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
    }

}

Client making the request:
import { Client } from "@stomp/stompjs";       // "@stomp/stompjs": "^7.0.0"

useEffect(() => {
        if (selectedChat) {
            fetchChatMessages(selectedChat.id).then((data: MessageType[]) => {                
                setMessages(data);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }

        const client = new Client({
            brokerURL: 'ws://localhost:8080/mysocket-websocket',
            connectHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
            },
            onConnect: () => {
                console.log("Connected to socket")
            },
            onStompError: (err) => {
                console.error(err);
            }
        });

        client.activate();

        // Clean up function to disconnect when the component is unmounted
        return () => {
            client.deactivate();
        };
    }, [selectedChat]);


Note: This part is related to the thread with @i_m_js.
SecurityConfig:
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    return http.httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/stomp").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("peer-tutoring-chat-websocket").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/peer-tutoring-chat-websocket").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                        //.authenticated()
                )
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers("/tbd"))
                .build();
}



Are you getting 401 when the WS connection is initiated?

@i_m_js No, I'm not getting any 401 codes

can you add your SecurityFIlterChain config in the question

Spring Boot adds AutoConfiguration as soon as you put the dependency to the project. Please check out: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-security-autoconfiguration
If you add a application.properties with spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration it should work again.

Unfortunately this solution does not work and the behaviour remains the same.

Since you are using bearer token based authentication using JWTs, you might have set the session creation policy as STATELESS. If the previous statement is true in your case, then you might be passing the Authorization header via your script for the private APIs, and might have used a filter to process it in your spring backend. 
To establish a WebSocket connection, browser first makes a HTTP handshake. In that HTTP request, browser will ask for a connection upgrade to WebSocket protocol. Since this http request is sent by browser, we will not be able to set any header including the Authorization header which might be needed by spring security filters to authenticate user.
I have noticed that chromium based browsers (Chrome, Edge) are not showing any information in response header if the http handshake had failed due to authentication. But on the otherhand, Firefox shows 403 error in the network tab. So the issue is with authenticating the user when the handshake HTTP call from the browser.
Like other problems there are many ways to solve this issue, one of them is to enable the websocket http url to all in the security configuration and then add a ChannelInterceptor to authenticate user using the auth token sent in the Stomp headers. You can find additional information from the following links
For a quick summary refer: How to use STOMP with Spring Security 
For a detailed answer: Websocket Authentication and Authorization in Spring 

Aldoe this response seems promising, it did not fix my problem. I replaced all the deprecated methods and classes with the current standard ones but the result stays the same.

Can you please try to configure your spring SecurityFilterChain to permit all requests into the system for non-authenticated requests also. If the issue persists, please share your observations here

I have followed the tutorial without any success. For the sake of testing I allowed all requests in my securityFilterChain. In the original question you can see how I did it. The behaviour stays the same with the client throwing Websocket connection errors.

I had made a similar CSRF configuration as you have, It still worked for me. A better option is to share a simple project with a similar setup. which will be helpful. And also you can enable debug logs and see if any exception is printed in the logs.
